# PHP - How to prevent user from logging in from multiple machines at the same time?

Tags: php

Is there a way that I can prevent a user from logging into a system from different machines at the same time?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with all these solutions based on IP address is that if a user is behind a proxy server that routes their request via multiple IP addresses, this may fail in a way that means the user cannot remain logged in.

What you can do instead is just, when any user logs in, give them a new session token and expire all previous session tokens belonging to the same user.

This would require you keeping a table of all valid session tokens and which user they're associated with.  Note that the built-in session handling of PHP is unlikely to be able to do this without much modification.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a better solution. You could also use JavaScript to *poll* the client, and if no polls within 15 minutes, expire session. To combat non JavaScript users, extend the expiry on every page load.

Comment: Yes, though I'd personally go the non-Javascript route, extending the expiry on every page load of an existing session - for that.

Comment: @alex Why poll at all? How can it help?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Poll Whoops, that should of been to poll the server, to extend a browser window sitting there, if you'd like to do that. Though you can argue that for security, it is best to leave idle browser sessions and let them expiry naturally.

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs in, put their IP address into a database.  If their IP changes, require them to log in again.

Even easier would be to save their SessionID.  If that changes, invalidate the old session.

Comment: shouldn't it be the opposite actually? if a user logs in from a different machine, the IP will be the same!

Comment: The IP will be the same if the two machines are behind a Firewall/NAT(e.g. a corporate network, home network, etc.). If they are not, then they will most likely have different IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent this.  And shouldn't.
Instead you have to manually logout everyone who logged in before.
Just keep track of session id in the users database and close a session if it's id is not equal to one, stored in the database after succesful login.
That will make all simultaneous users login constantly and ruin all their efforts to use your service.

Comment: OMG stupid monkeys strikes again. None of these theorists ever implemented such a mechanism in real, but everyone's up with their solution and opinion.

Comment: Why you are you saying that s/he can't prevent this? it can be done, maybe is not performance or not the greatest idea but it can be done.

Comment: +1 I agree to an extent. Limiting a session to an IP address is error prone and will prevent legitimate users from accessing your site.

Comment: +1 Because I'll agree you can't do it foolproof. I don't know why you were downvoted so bad, but perhaps don't fly off the handle either when it happens ;)

Comment: The fact that this is something you probably shouldn't do is something I didn't think about when I wrote my answer.  It's true that it's better to let users log in from multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the users' IP address in the database when the login and clear that IP when they logout (or you log them out). If a user attempts to login but they already have a different IP stored in the database that could be an indication that they are logging in from 2 different machines....not 100% accurate but may sorta work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping track of the current (last) IP that the user logged in from.  When the user logs in, change that IP.  Make checking current IP against the last IP part of your authentication procedure; if it's different, log them out.  The can then log back in, but that'd result in kicking the other machine's login off.