# detecting session_destroy/end of session, limit session logins to 1

Tags: php, session

I added code to update Mysql in a column that tracks if a user is logged in or not, to prevent multiple logins at the same time and track how many users are currently logged in at any given time from an admin panel. This did not seem to work as I am able to login on multiple browser tabs. (They all seem to share the same session id. If I logout on one tab I am then logged out on all other tabs)

When I added the code below I then get logged out **if I click any link**. (This code is on a header.php file that is included on all of my webpages. Do you know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Are there other ways to detect a session ending and/or session_destroy? Is there a way I can fix this system to prevent multiple logins or another way I can accomplish that goal?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

```
if(session_destroy()){

$sql="UPDATE login
SET loggedin = '0'
WHERE username='$member_id' "; 

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

As a note, I noticed in my barrowed code in logout.php (my logout script)  "if(session_destroy())" seems to be used to logout and redirect to homepage which does work. (however, I'm not sure how session_destroy() can execute when placed inside of a conditional statement. Here is the code:

```
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: hash.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to prevent user from logging in from multiple machines at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473921/php-how-to-prevent-user-from-logging-in-from-multiple-machines-at-the-same-tim)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using "onbeforeunload" and linking it to my logout.php script with ajax. On the logout.php script I have a mysli statement that sets the table column loggedin = 0. This way if the user forgets to logout and just closes the tab or the browser they will automatically be logged out and mysql table will still be updated as to their logged in status.